# Why my javascript DOM doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my whole page. I have no idea what's wrong. It's so frustrating because it is so simple.

When i'm trying to get out the value if my input fields it gives back nothing. Even if i make an alert before AJAX it writes out nothing. I copied an input dom get under mine and it was exactly the same one.

What's wrong?

registration.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["php_username"]) && isset($_POST["php_password"]) && isset($_POST["php_password2"]) && isset($_POST["php_email"])){
        $error = "";
        if(strlen($_POST["php_username"]) < 8){
            $error = $error."Username has to be at least 8 characters.<br>";
        }
        if(strlen($_POST["php_password"]) < 8){
            $error = $error."password has to be at least 8 characters.<br>";
        }
        if(strlen($_POST["php_username"]) > 16){
            $error = $error."Username can't be more than 16 characters.<br>";
        }
        if(strlen($_POST["php_password"]) < 16){
            $error = $error."Password can't be more than 16 characters.<br>";
        }
        if(strcmp($_POST["php_password"],$_POST["php_password2"])){
            $error = $error."Password confirmation falied.<br>";
        }
        echo($error);

    }else{
        echo('
            <div id="register-form">
                <form>
                    <h2 style="text-decoration: underline; margin-bottom: 10px;">Registration</h2><br><br>
                    Username:<br>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="16" id="username" value="asd" /><br>
                    Password:<br>
                    <input type="password" maxlength="16" id="password" /><br>
                    Confirm password:<br>
                    <input type="password" maxlength="16" id="password2" /><br>
                    E-mail address:<br>
                    <input type="email" id="email" /><br><br>
                    <input type="button" id="registration-submit" value="Signup"><br>
                    <div id="registration-response">                        
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <script>
                $("#registration-submit").click(function(){
                    var username = document.getElementById("username").value; 
                    var password = document.getElementById("password").value; 
                    var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value; 
                    var email = document.getElementById("email").value; 

                    $.post("registration.php",{
                        "php_username": username,
                        "php_password": password,
                        "php_password2": password2,
                        "php_email": email
                    },
                    function(data, status){
                        $("#registration-response").html(data);
                        $("#registration-response").fadeIn(750);
                    });

                });
            </script>
        ');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you included the jquery? because i hope it will give you $ undefined error.

Comment: Yes, i did it on index.php. This page has been loaded into a div with jquery. The page gives no javascript error.

Comment: so either include jquery file or use document everywhere to avoid $

Comment: Jquery is included on this page, it is working(for example with the button). registration.php is loaded to a div on index.php.

Comment: Not sure if i understood your problem correctly. Is it when fetching the input values? Just copied your code, added an alert before the post and the values are correctly displayed after clicking the submit button. Did have to add jQuery to the page though.

Answer (score 0):

just put your javascript outside echo statement and also wrap it inside `$(document).ready();`

```
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST["php_username"]) && isset($_POST["php_password"]) && isset($_POST["php_password2"]) && isset($_POST["php_email"])){
                $error = "";
                if(strlen($_POST["php_username"]) < 8){
                    $error = $error."Username has to be at least 8 characters.<br>";
                }
                if(strlen($_POST["php_password"]) < 8){
                    $error = $error."password has to be at least 8 characters.<br>";
                }
                if(strlen($_POST["php_username"]) > 16){
                    $error = $error."Username can't be more than 16 characters.<br>";
                }
                if(strlen($_POST["php_password"]) < 16){
                    $error = $error."Password can't be more than 16 characters.<br>";
                }
                if(strcmp($_POST["php_password"],$_POST["php_password2"])){
                    $error = $error."Password confirmation falied.<br>";
                }
                echo($error);

            }else{
                echo('
                    <div id="register-form">
                        <form>
                            <h2 style="text-decoration: underline; margin-bottom: 10px;">Registration</h2><br><br>
                            Username:<br>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="16" id="username" value="asd" /><br>
                            Password:<br>
                            <input type="password" maxlength="16" id="password" /><br>
                            Confirm password:<br>
                            <input type="password" maxlength="16" id="password2" /><br>
                            E-mail address:<br>
                            <input type="email" id="email" /><br><br>
                            <input type="button" id="registration-submit" value="Signup"><br>
                            <div id="registration-response">                        
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>');


    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registration-submit").click(function(){
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value; 
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value; 
        var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value; 
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value; 

        $.post("registration.php",{
            "php_username": username,
            "php_password": password,
            "php_password2": password2,
            "php_email": email
             },
         function(data, status){
             $("#registration-response").html(data);
             $("#registration-response").fadeIn(750);
             });

           });
       });                    

   </script>

            }
        ?>
```

Comment: I have no idea why should that make a different. $(document).redy() doesn't need since my script is after the html. Outside or insed php the same, why would it matter?